# Decrementing value in firebase using react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to decrement the Quantity value in Firebase realtime database, when a button is clicked. However, I have tried multiple methods still unable to decrement the value. Listed below is what the structure looks like.

```js
const database = [
  {
    Name: "Coca Cola",
    Price: "1.75",
    Quantity: "66",
  },
  {
    Name: "HaagenDaz",
    Price: "3.99",
    Quantity: "5",
  },
  {
    Name: "Trident",
    Price: "1.85",
    Quantity: "10",
  },
  {
    Name: "kitkat",
    Price: "1.20",
    Quantity: "100",
  },
];
```

One of the methods I used to decrement Quantity value for Trident to 9 is:   `Quantity:  firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)` the result was:

```js
{
  "Name": "Trident",
  "Price": "1.85",
  "Quantity": {
    "d_": {
      "J_": -1,
      "_methodName": "FieldValue.increment"
    }
  }
}
```

the expected result should've been:

```js
{
  Name: "Trident", 
  Price: "1.85", 
  Quantity: "9"
}
```

I posted the code below:

```js
Object.values(this.state.mylist).map((key) => {
  const target = key;
  const string = this.state.paredString;

  console.log("Quantity:", target.Quantity);
  // const ref_forUpdate = firebase.database().ref("Product Name");
  // const decrement = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1);

  const name = target.Name;
  const qty = target.Quantity;
  // const decrement = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1);
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (target.Name == string[i]) {
      // let temp = target.Quantity
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref("Product Name/" + name)
        .update({
          // Quantity:  firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1) //<------ creates a new sub-branch under Quantity
          // Quantity: qty - 1 ,  <------ Quantity in realtime database keeps decreasing without stopping
        });
      console.log("Matched:", target);
    } else {
      console.log("Not_matched2");
    }
  }
  console.log("\n");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the operator for Firestore, but are writing to the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, and both support atomic increments/decrements, the API is different.

For the Realtime Database, the field is named `ServerValue.increment()`, so:

```
firebase.database().ref("Product Name/" + name).update({
  Quantity: ServerValue.increment(-1)
})
```

Comment: thank you for the help it worked I was able to decrement the value, but the issue that i am keep running into is that it just keeps decreasing its value with out stopping.

Comment: Thank you so much it helped a lot I was able to resolve the issue.